# Autoconfig prevent my website redirection to https

Tags: apache

I have a website in an apache server and a mail server in the same machine.  I want the port 80 request redirecting to https 443 port, so I put it in the vhost configuration.

I also want an autoconfig (Mozilla thunderbird use) for my mailserver. However I need to put a config-v1.1.xml accessible on port 80.

The problem is when I request http://example.com it's does not redirect to https://example.com like I want to but it redirects to the autoconfig.

Is there a way to keep autoconfig and have a redirection to https://example.com ?

I have setup a dns record for autoconfig.example.com and call it in vhost file but when I type mysite.com, it still goes in the autoconfig.

Any clues ?
Thanks

Here is the autoconfig.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
<VirtualHost 178.33.235.19:80>
    ServerName autoconfig.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/autoconfig/
    <Directory /var/www/html/autoconfig>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the site vhost example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    #SSL Config
    SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/STAR_example_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/STAR_example_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        LogLevel crit
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/example-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/example-access_log common

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you show us your whole vhosts file?

Comment: I've put it below

Comment: Please edit it inside the question.